# Selection texture on tiles causing performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, xna, selection, tile

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Vector2 mouseCoord = GetMouseTilePosition();
                if (mouseCoord.X > 0)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(selection, tileRect = new Rectangle((int)mouseCoord.X * 64, (int)mouseCoord.Y * 64, 64, 64),
                                    Color.White);
                }
                spriteBatch.Draw(tiles[index[x,y]].texture, tileRect = new Rectangle(x * 64, y * 64, 64, 64), 
                    Color.White);          
            }
        }  
    }

    public Vector2 GetMouseTilePosition()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                if (IsMouseInsideTile(x, y))
                {
                    return new Vector2(x, y);
                }
            }
        }

        return new Vector2(-1, -1);
    }

    public bool IsMouseInsideTile(int x, int y)
    {
        MouseState MS = Mouse.GetState();
        return (MS.X >= x * 64 && MS.X <= (x + 1) * 64 &&
            MS.Y >= y * 64 && MS.Y <= (y + 1) * 64);
    }
```

It is very cpu intensive. Is there a better way to do this code? Also I have a camera how can I change this to factor that in so I get the actual mouse position

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What are `width` and `height`? Why are you calling `GetMouseTilePosition` (which loops over *every* coordinate) on *every iteration* within `Draw`? Basically, yes - I'm absolutely sure there are *much* faster ways of doing this, but it's hard to give suggestions without more context.

Comment: I just didn't include all my code. width = 17 height = 15. I was told to use GetMouseTilePosition in my last question, so yeah that's why I'm using that

Comment: To be honest, that code looks pretty inefficient to start with. It's still not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Its a simple tile engine with nested for loops. How is that inefficient? I'm trying to get a square selection texture of the tile that my mouse is currently over. I don't understand how to explain that anymore.

Comment: How is that inefficient? Well, you're executing the innermost loop 15*17*15*17=65025 times. Sounds pretty inefficient to me, compared with what I suspect is required. You haven't explained in *this* question what tiles you have, nor even what *class* this is. Is it a representation of a single tile, or are there multiple tiles *within* this class? What do you mean by "square selection texture", *exactly*? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It draws my map 17x15. I posted the portion of code where the issue is. I'm not gonna post a book then no one will want to read all of it. There is 2 tiles. A texture that shows what tile is selected, literally a square texture with transparent center that goes around the edge of the tile. My code all works perfectly the way I want besides the selection, which is what the question pertains to.

Comment: Okay, if you don't want to put the effort into explaining what you're trying to achieve, that's fine - I'll move on. Best of luck. (I wasn't suggesting posting more *code* necessarily by the way - but more *descriptive text*.)

Comment: Dude the square texture is a square that surrounds the tile. Like in minecraft how it has the black come up on the tile when you mouse over, but instead 2D. How can I explain it any better? Seriously.

Comment: Seriously? Edit your question to give: 1) A description of what class this code is in. 2) A description of what `tiles` is - we have no idea. 3) A description of what it's meant to do. Readers shouldn't have to gather information from various comments in two questions. Ideally, don't rely on readers having played Minecraft, either. (I haven't, for example.) Posting a screenshot of the correct behaviour could help *hugely*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Skeet is right, you could directly call IsMouseInsideTile() instead of looping through your array several times. (Currently, you're checking where the mouse is in the whole tile array, for each tile, instead of only checking the current tile you're in).

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            if (IsMouseInsideTile(x, y))
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(selection, tileRect = new Rectangle(x * 64, y * 64, 64, 64),
                                    Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(tiles[index[x,y]].texture, tileRect = new Rectangle(x * 64, y * 64, 64, 64), 
                    Color.White);          
        }
    }  
}
```

I'm sorry, it's all my fault, I submitted this code quickly earlier without double checking.  This new version should improve your performance drastically.

Comment: Its cool. One more question if you wouldn't mind answering. Everything I look up online about mouse picking says to use .contains or .intersects on rectangles for your mouse and tiles. Do you think that would be a better way to do it or stick with what you gave me? I just want to do whatever will be more optimized in the long run

Comment: I guess you could use .intersect, but I don't think there would be much difference performance wise. You would have to try out yourself and see if it makes a difference.